# Get TaxonomySession TermStore TermSet Term from Sharepoint 2010 Server using Microsoft.Sharepoint.Client.Taxonomy.dll

Tags: 2010, client-object-model, taxonomy

I'm coding a c++/c# client-application to communicate with a Sharepoint 2010 site which uses Taxonomy

I have downloaded and installed `Microsoft.Sharepoint.Client.Taxonomy.dll` from:
http://download.microsoft.com/download/E/1/9/E1987F6C-4D0A-4918-AEFE-12105B59FF6A/sharepointclientcomponents_x64.msi

The client user may enter values in a form by selecting values from a dropdown of values collected from a Taxonomy TermSet. In order to fetch the TermSet I must first get a TaxonomySession:

```
TaxonomySession taxonomySession = TaxonomySession.GetTaxonomySession(clientContext);
clientContext.Load(taxonomySession, 
    ts => ts.TermStores.Include(
    store => store.Name,
    store => store.Groups.Include(
    group => group.Name))
);
try
{
    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    string err = e.Message; // Cannot find proxy for type with id "{981cbc68-9edc-4f8d-872f-71146fcbb84f}"
}
```

**Error message: Cannot find proxy for type with id "{981cbc68-9edc-4f8d-872f-71146fcbb84f}"**

I'm uncertain whether the reason is that it is illegal to use `Microsoft.Sharepoint.Client.Taxonomy.dll` (Sharepoint 2013) against a Sharepoint 2010 server or whether I'm doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

If you are connecting to Sharepoint 2010, then you need to download the SharePoint SDK for 2010. 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff847473(v=office.14).aspx

This is the reference for the Sharepoint 2010 TaxonomySession Class: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.taxonomy.taxonomysession(office.14).aspx

Comment: The client-application is a windows executable running on client computers and must do the job using Microsoft.Sharepoint.Client.Taxonomy.dll
Both your links point to documentation regarding Microsoft.Sharepoint.Taxonomy.dll

Comment: ...because SharePoint 2010 doesn't support Taxonomy from the CSOM.. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj163949.aspx